# Get a response with the remainder of the request

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to separate the two numbers and get the answer with the remainder.

```
select 13/5;
```

I get an answer `2`.

I add types.

```
select 13::numeric/5::numeric;
```

I get an answer `2.6000000000000000`.

But I need only one number after the decimal point. How do I get `2.6`?

Comment: When you say you only need one number after the decimal, what are you storing the result in?  Is it to be stored as text, or a number?

Comment: @Martin I want it to be a number

Comment: With a flexible number of decimals, with trailing 0's removed?

Comment: What do you want for 5/4? (And 4/3?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like so:

```
SELECT (13.0 / 5.0)::numeric(10, 1)
```

The `.0` tells PG that it is a numeric literal. Division of two numerics result in numeric.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ROUND`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html) to restrict to 1 decimal place. Note that you only need to cast the first value as numeric:

```
SELECT ROUND(13::numeric/5, 1)
```

Output

```
2.6
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```sql
select round(13::numeric/5::numeric, 1);
```

https://www.w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/round-function.php

Answer (score 1):

If you want it displayed in that fashion, you should convert the result to a string with the proper format:

```
SELECT to_char(13::numeric / 5::numeric, '9999.9999FM');

 to_char 
---------
 2.6
(1 row)
```